# Associative array's loaded from database and display as 'columns'

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, associative

I am trying to create an overview of product properties, for an invoice system.
So far, most things are comming together using classes and PDO.
I have the following issue.

In my class, i've created a function that builds my products array.
It loads some information from the database, to build this array.
This array, i want to use to display all the products i have selected:

**$prod1 - $prod1Name - $prod1Descr - $prod1Price

$prod2 - $prod2name - $prod2Descr - $prod2Price

etc.**

I figured that the *Associative array* would help me creating *columns*.
Though the problem is, that i do not understand a bit how to create multiple lines and columns this way.
I was thinking of something like:
**$prod[1]["name"] - $prod[1]["descr"] - etc**
Then to use this in a foreach loop to create as many new lines as required.
The only thing i could come up with is on my index.php (as shown below), cause using an index (the [1] defenition) does not seem to work the way i think it should be implemented.

For my understanding, i assigend the var in my class as an array, then redefine an array when loading the database information.
Could anyone tell me how i could try to solve this issue?

---

I have the following class:

```
    <?    
    class Invoice{

        var $vendorID;
        var $product = array();

            function product_array(){
                global $db;
                $query = $db->conn->prepare('
                SELECT ProductName, ProductDescription, ProductDuration, ProductPriceInclVat, ProductPriceExclVat, ProductVatType
                FROM products WHERE VendorID = :VendorID
                ');

                $array = array (
                    'VendorID' => $this->vendorID
                );

                $query->execute($array);

                $result = $query->fetchall();

                if (empty($result)){
                    echo"Could not find any products matching your criteria.";
                    die;
                } else {
                        foreach($result as $row) {
                            $this->product = array("Name" => $row['ProductName'],
                                                    "Description" => $row['ProductDescription'],
                                                    "Duration" => $row['ProductDuration'],
                                                    "PriceExclVat" => $row['ProductPriceExclVat'],
                                                    "PriceInclVat" => $row['ProductPriceInclVat'],
                                                    "VatType" => $row['ProductVatType']
                                                    );
                        }

                }       
            }
        }
?>
```

and then i have the following code on my index.php:

```
<?
$invoice = new Invoice();

foreach ($invoice->product as $key => $value){
    echo $key . "<br>";
    echo $value . "$value";

    echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are assigning the result arrays to the product property you are overwriting the array every time. You need to append to the array instead, so something like:

```
$this->product = array();
foreach($result as $row) {
    $this->product[] = array(...);
}
```

Alternatively, you could just assign the results of fetchAll to the product property if you don't need to rename the field keys (or you could alias them in the SQL).

Comment: thank you for your response. I modified my class as you suggested. Therefor, i changed my index.php and added the following code:

'foreach ($invoice->product[$row] as $key => $value){
 echo $value;
}'
Yet this gives me errors, am i thinking correctly?

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = $db->conn->prepare('
                SELECT ProductName as Name,
                ProductDescription as Description, 
                ProductDuration as Duration, 
                ProductPriceInclVat as PriceInclVat, 
                ProductPriceExclVat as PriceExclVat, 
                ProductVatType as VatType
                FROM products WHERE VendorID = :VendorID
                ');

                $array = array (
                    'VendorID' => $this->vendorID
                );

                $query->execute($array);

                $product = $query->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

The $product is now in the format you require.
After this you can avoid foreach loop in class invoice.
Other thing i noticed that you have made function product_array() which is not called,
so in index.php you are getting empty array (defined in class Invoice).
So in Invoice class it should be

```
$product = product_array()
```

and product_array function should return the value.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I did not think about the FETCH_ASSOC. The product_array() is set in the constructor, i didn't want to put hundrets line of irrelevant code, sorry for that. So i have modifed the code as you described, but that leaves me with the issue that i still dont understand how to call the variables on my index.php for displaying the results. Both using echo $invoice->product["ProductDuration"]; or the foreachloop neither seem to work. Any suggestions for me?